# http post successfully logged in?

Tags: android, http, authentication, https, http-post

I am trying to login to a webside which needs 3 parameters in the post command.
Token, usr_name and usr_password.

The token always has the following value "545616f1e29bc538843ec7aa908122b1e".
I am getting this value by doing a HttpGet on the loginpage and store it as a string.

If i do a login through the url as follows https://www.xxxxx.com/xxxx/restricted/form/formelement=0123?usr_name=myuser&usr_password=mypass&token=545616f1e29bc538843ec7aa908122b1e the login succeeds.

How do i get a.m link build together and know afterwards that i successfully logged in?
Thanks for any tips and helping me out.

My code:

```
try {
            String webPage = "https://xxxxxxxx.com/xx/Authenticationserv";
            String name = username; // user input through editbox
            String password1 = password; // user input through editbox

            String authString = name + ":" + password1 + ":" + token + "=" + value;
            System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
            byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBytesToBytes(authString.getBytes());
            String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
            System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

            URL url = new URL(webPage);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

            int numCharsRead;
            char[] charArray = new char[1024];
            StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer();
            while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
                sb1.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
            }
            String result = sb1.toString();

            System.out.println("/// BEGIN ///");
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println("/// END ///");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you need to use `POST` method to log in in your website.I had the same problem a few weeks ago and I've did this :

```
    HttpClient httpclient;
    HttpPost httppost;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httppost = new HttpPost("your login link");


    postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username_hash", "fcd86e8cc9fc7596f102de7b2b922e80c6e6fac9"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_hash", "b66936348bd0bd44fa44f5ca7dcceb909545e47f"));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    Log.w("Response ","Status line : "+ response.toString());
```

So you are setting up your post params with an `ArrayList` and you can get the responce from the server if you logged in via `HttpResponse`.And another thing : I'm setting up the username and password in the code,because it is just to how you the idea.If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Android-Droid,

Thank you for the answer but if do the login with your code, and pass incorrect username i still get response 200.
So something is wrong.
PS: i added a the 3rd parameter to the postparameter.

Comment: Sorry actually that's the status of response, that's why you are getting 200 as result. See my edited answer.

Comment: Hi,
No worries but somehow something is msissing in the headers.
Through FireBug i can see that the requested headers are:
- Host access.xxxx.com
- User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2
- Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
- Accept-Language nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
- Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
- Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
- Connection keep-alive
- Referer http://www.xxxx.com/prive/mysession/login.htm
Any suggestions?
I think i am getting close.
Thx again for helping me.

Comment: Be sure that you use the right link for log in and sending the right log in params,or just update your code so I can help you more.

Comment: Hi Android-Droid,
I need your help, as i am getting no where, i am totally confused, is it possible to communicate via email?
Thx

Comment: Hi Android-Droid,
Just sent you an email.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it.I'm at work now.I'll see what I can do later.Just a quick tip,as you said..if web server needs ssl sertification, you have to know what kind of ssl he needs.And probably that's why you can't login in website.

Comment: Good morning Android-Droid,
I sent you an email of what i have reached for now, did you already have the chance to have a look at the site?
I am curious about you`re opinion to get this done.
Krgds,

Comment: Sorry dude, I had a lots of work to do yesterday.I'm preparing to release a beta version of an application...so i guess the weekend I will look at your problem and try to find a solution.

Comment: No problem dude,
Just take it easy, i`m on it for 2 weeks now, so a couple of days do not matter :)
Talke to you later..

Comment: Hi Android-Droid,
How is it going with the beta version? Hope fine.
I sent you a short email, if you gor the time please have a look.
Thx.

Comment: Hi Dude,could you please let me know something?
Is something wrong?
Thx

Comment: Hi Android-Droid,
Hope you`re fine.
I can chat now, is it possible to have a chat?
Thx in advance.